Salesforce, Azure Speech SDK Error: Lightning Web Security: Unsupported MIME type
I want to implement the Azure Speech to text in LWC, but I got an issue: Lightning Web Security: Unsupported MIME type.

Step 1: I upload the sdk file (https://aka.ms/csspeech/jsbrowserpackageraw) into Static Resources.
Step 2: Using loadScript to load js file.

import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import SPEECH_SDK from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/speechSDKBundle';

export default class SpeechToElement extends LightningElement {
    mediaRecorder;
    audioChunks = [];
    audioUrl;
    isRecording = false;
    isPaused = false;
    recognizer;
    sdkLoaded = false;

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.sdkLoaded) {
            return;
        }
        this.sdkLoaded = true;
        
        loadScript(this, SPEECH_SDK)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Azure Speech SDK loaded successfully.');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error loading Azure Speech SDK', error);
            });
    }


Step 3: Create a Recognizer. The error will appear when this.recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync() is running.

        try{
            // configure Azure STT to listen to an audio Stream
            const audioConfig = window.SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();

            const speechConfig = window.SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription('mykey', 'myregion');
            speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-AU";
            // recognizer is a global variable
            this.recognizer = new window.SpeechSDK.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig)

            this.recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(
                function (result) {
                  console.log(result);
                  this.recognizer.close();
                  this.recognizer = undefined;
                },
                function (err) {
                  console.error(err);
                  this.recognizer.close();
                  this.recognizer = undefined;
                });
        }catch (error) {
            console.error("Error in handleStart", error);
        }
    }

